# Class in PHPStorm shows red line

Tags: php

The filename has a wavy red line but I do not see an error popping up in the class I created. Is this an error of PHPStorm? There is no indication that I am missing something. And hovering over the red line does not show more info.

[image]

```
<?php

namespace App\Classes;

use App\Events\EventGenerator;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Classes\User;

class User extends Model {

    use EventGenerator;

    // Define Table Setup with fillabe fields
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'user_reference', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'user_type_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
    public $timestamps = true;

    // Set class properties
    public function set($data) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $this->{$key} = $value;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function getAllUsers() {
        $responders = User::all();
        return $responders;
    }


    public function getUser($userReference) {
        $user = User::where('user_reference', '=', $userReference)->first();
        return $user;
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be complaining you are using the class in the same file you are defining the class

Comment: Try hovering over the underlined class name. You will get a tooltip indicating the reason why it is marked.

Comment: Actually the tooltip is not appearing... unfortunately

Comment: @sesc360 tried removing this? `use App\Classes\User;`

Comment: Can it be, that I am not allowed to use the User class in Laravel to extend it for my own purposes?

Comment: When I tried to add the namespace in another class, an error popped up when I used `User`. I changed the class name now it works well